# How can I make the Jmeter process exact number of samples within the given duration of time?

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

I have to exactly process 26.5K samples in an hour duration as part of soak test in non GUI mode.
I have tried some approaches but I couldn't exactly process 26.5K users in an hour duration.

When 26.5K is equally divided for an hour, I could get 7.36 users per second

1. So I tried giving 7 users, rampup-1sec, loopcount-infinite and duration-1hour, with constant throughput timer set to 420 req/sec but it ended up giving me total processed samples as 25118
2. I even tried giving 8 users, rampup-1sec, loopcount-infinite and duration-1hour, with constant throughput timer set to 480 req/sec but it ended up giving me total processed samples as 28700

Would be helpful if I could get any other approach where I could exactly process 26.5K users or somewhere around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most precise way seems to be [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-shaping-timer-plugin)

1. Make throughput a little bit higher, i.e. 7.37

   [image]
2. Additionally put your Sampler under the [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) and set Total Throughput to be 26500 so you won't get higher samplers number:

   [image]

Comment: Thanks Much @Dmitri T, able to solve my issue with the second step. Thanks for your timely help.